# Can a user copy data from a spreadsheet and send it (paste it) to a "master" spreadsheet without having permissions on the latter?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a simple spreadsheet app for users (work colleagues) to submit performance evaluations at the end of the year. I am interested in them being able to edit spreadsheet A and submit the data to spreadsheet B (database) via a button. Problem is data in spreadsheet B is private/sensible and having to share it with everyone wouldn't work out.

I have got the code working already but users are getting an alert when submitting the data. I am guessing this is because they don't have spreadsheet B shared. They are getting this message: "Document X is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)".

```
//Displays spreadsheet use instructions.
function showInstructions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('IMPORTANTE: Haz una copia del documento marcado como (Template) y trabaja sobre ella. \n \n Instrucciones: \n 1. Renombra la copia que creaste como “RecursosHumanos-EvaluadorDeDesempeno-TuNombre. \n 2. Lee los comentarios de cada rubro a evaluar desplazando el cursor/mouse por su encabezado. \n 3. Evalúa a tus colegas. \n 4. Ingresa los datos en el menú BIMmx > Submit.');
}

//Displays thanks banner after submitting form.
function showThanks() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('¡Gracias por participar!');
}

//Pops instructions and creates menus.
function onOpen() {   

  showInstructions();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuButtons = [ {name: "Submit", functionName: "submit"} ];
  ss.addMenu("BIMmx", menuButtons);
}

function submit() {
  askName();
  copyData();
  showThanks();
  clear();
}

//Asks for user name before submitting data to master sheet.
function askName() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Display prompt.
  var result; 
  var text = "";

  while (text == ""){
    result = ui.prompt(
      '¡Completa la evaluación!',
      'Ingresa tu nombre:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    text = result.getResponseText();
    if (text == "") 
      ui.alert('Nombre no puede estar vacío.');
    else if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      // User clicked "OK".
      ui.alert('Tu nombre es ' + text + '.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('No entendí eso.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Cerraste el diálogo.');
    }


  }

 fillUser(text);

}

//Fills rows with submitting username.
function fillUser(result) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("K2").setValue(result);  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, lc, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("K2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}

//Backup data to master spreadsheet.  
function copyData(result) {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('InsertYourURL'); //I would just open by id
  var sh=sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var sData=rg.getValues();
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('Output'); 
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sData.length,sData[0].length).setValues(sData);

}

//Clean sheet once submission is done.  
function clear() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Input');
  sheet.getRange('A2:H').clearContent();
}
}
```

I am copying the code altough it probably is not that relevant for this problem.

Would love to hear any ideas on how to work around this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try a webapp.  It can run as you and be executed by anyone.  I'd build it on a shared drive (use to be called a team drive) and let my colleagues join the team drive and that  will keep others from gaining access to the data.

Comment: We use Shared Drives so that may work. But I am not sure what you mean by web app. Do you have any examples or documentation I can follow? Thanks!

Comment: Documentation for [WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#top_of_page)

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it possible to build a web app on a Sheets interface? Keeping the app exactly as it works now but just submitting data as my account instead of theirs? Have you seen any example I can follow of this -Sheets Interface-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working with help from a good friend of mine and obviously @AndresDuarte. Thanks!

The answer was to: build a web app, send the data through that app so that it can be stamped as if it was sent by just one account (this way it doesn't recquire edit access from every user), and include some JSON and Array parsing to convert strings into matrixes.

This is the script.

**Spreadsheet Script**

```
//Displays spreadsheet use instructions.
function showInstructions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('IMPORTANTE: Haz una copia del documento marcado como (Template) y trabaja sobre ella. \n \n Instrucciones: \n 1. Renombra la copia que creaste como “RecursosHumanos-EvaluadorDeDesempeno-TuNombre. \n 2. Lee los comentarios de cada rubro a evaluar desplazando el cursor/mouse por su encabezado. \n 3. Evalúa a tus colegas. \n 4. Ingresa los datos en el menú BIMmx > Submit.');
}

//Displays thanks banner after submitting form.
function showThanks() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('¡Gracias por participar!');
}

//Pops instructions and creates menus.
function onOpen() {   

  showInstructions();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuButtons = [ {name: "Submit", functionName: "submit"} ];
  ss.addMenu("X", menuButtons);
}

function submit() {
  askName();
  copyData();
  showThanks();
  clear();
}

//Asks for user name before submitting data to master sheet.
function askName() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Display prompt.
  var result; 
  var text = "";

  while (text == ""){
    result = ui.prompt(
      '¡Completa la evaluación!',
      'Ingresa tu nombre:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    text = result.getResponseText();
    if (text == "") 
      ui.alert('Nombre no puede estar vacío.');
    else if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      // User clicked "OK".
      ui.alert('Tu nombre es ' + text + '.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('No entendí eso.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Cerraste el diálogo.');
    }


  }

 fillUser(text);

}

//Fills rows with submitting username.
function fillUser(result) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("K2").setValue(result);  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, lc, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("K2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}

//Backup data to master spreadsheet.  
function copyData() {

  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var sData=rg.getValues().join(";");

  //This is the Web App URL.
  var url = "Enter you URL here";  

  var payload = {    
    "sData" : JSON.stringify(sData),    
  }

  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload,
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //Logger.log(JSON.parse(result));  


}

//Clean sheet once submission is done.  
function clear() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Input');
  sheet.getRange('A2:K').clearContent();
}
```

**Web App Script**

```
function doPost(e) {

  var sData = JSON.parse(e.parameters.sData);  

  var response = {
    "status" : "FAILED",
    "sData" : sData,
  };  

  sData = sData.split(";");

  //Convert 1D array to 2D array
  for(var i = 0; i < sData.length ; i++) {
    sData[i] = sData[i].split(",");
  }

  //Use your spreadsheetID to get Output Sheet
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Enter your ID here.');
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('Output');

  //Use setValues() function to put the 2D array into Sheet 
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sData.length,sData[0].length).setValues(sData);

  MailApp.sendEmail("Enter your email here","New Response","A new response has been registered.");  

  var response = {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "sData" : sData,
  };     

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Web App [1] with a doPost() function implemented, where the script can manipulate the Spreadsheet as if it were you. When you publish the Web App you need to set the option "Execute the app as:" to "me".

From the script of your source Spreadsheet you would make the post request sending the data from the source sheet as a string to your Web App using the fetch() function [2], you only need to change the copyData function to this:

```
function copyData(result) {

  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var sData=rg.getValues().join(";");

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : sData
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('[Web App URL]', options);
}
```

In the Web App script you would manipulate the received data, first converting the string to a 2D array and then editing your destination Sheet. The doPost function would be like this:

```
function doPost(e) {
  //Get the data from the fetch call  
  var sData = e.postData.contents;

  //Convert string to a 1D array
  var sData = sData.split(";");

  //Convert 1D array to 2D array
  for(var i=0; i<sData.length ; i++) {
    sData[i] = sData[i].split(",");
  }

  //Use your spreadsheetID to get Output Sheet
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET-ID'); //I would just open by id
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('Output');

  //Use setValues() function to put the 2D array into Sheet 
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sData.length,sData[0].length).setValues(sData);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('');
}
```

I tested your code with the mentioned changes and worked as expected from users without permissions in the target Spreadsheet.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

Comment: This is excellent! One question, though. When you say "in the Web App script" do you mean in the same script I am currently working on?

Comment: I used the Publish > Deploy as a web app from directly from the spreadsheet script. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, update. I modified my script with the first part from yours, @andres and added the second part to a new script that I published as a web app. On the first script, I integrated the web app URL (that has te second part of the script you shared) as it appears on the browser and when I run it It appears I'm not getting any errors **but** I am not getting any data either.. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you mean that when you run "UrlFetchApp.fetch" you just get an empty response, that is the intended behaviour of the code. The part where the spreadsheet is manipulated is inside the doPost function in the Web App, so when you make the post call, it will manipulate the spreadsheet and return an empty string. If you want to change the response you're getting, you need to change the return value for the doPost() function.

Comment: And if you're testing the URL from the browser, remember this is a post method and not a get method which is the one used by browsers.

Comment: Ok, @Andres. So let me see if I am getting this right. The copyData function sends the values to the independent web app via the UrlFetchApp.fetch method. The web app gets the data (via the fetch URL) and the data is now there. Now, when does this data get copied to the database spreadsheet `dss` in the original script? And how? Thanks for helping out btw. If I ever get this to work it'll be because of you.

Comment: I edited the answer with comments in the doPost() function, if you don't understand something check the App Script and/or JavaScript documentation. No worries, I'm glad I was able to help.